# Exporting Data From app.powerbi.com fails with message content enable

Tags: powerbi

Each time I select 'Analyze in Excel' I get the message 'Failed to open file in Excel ..... so the file has been dowloaded to your computer'.

My attempts to open the downloaded excel file fails.

I first get the following screen after opening the file

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

After 'enabling content' I get the following error message:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATUTD.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKUbH.png